# Bike measurements vs my measurements

Tags: frames

I would like to buy a used Rose Pro DX Cross bike (model 2014 or 2015) and its size is listed as being ST-56 cm and TT - 54 cm. I'm 178 cm in height and my inseam length is 79 cm. Do you think it's suitable for me? I don't want the top tube to hurt my groin when I dismount it to wait at traffic lights or anything like that. Thanks a million!

Best wishes,
Florin

Answer (score 4):

The only real way to determine if a bike fits you is to sit on it and ideally ride it.

In addition to making sure the stand-over clearance and set height range are OK, you need to determine if the position of the handlebars relative to the seat works for you. Lower, forward bars means a more aggressive riding position, higher rearward bars allows a more relaxed riding position.

Comment: Totally agree.  2 minutes over a bike is enough to decide  "no"   Ideally you want a middling length ride before deciding "yes" but that may not be workable.   Sight unseen buying is a heck of a risk.

Comment: A 56cm ST height on that bike is quite high for a 178cm height. I own that same bike in 54cm ST, the top tube is 80cm from the road surface. I'm 183cm with the same 79cm in-seam.  (Go to the ROSE website and check their recommendations. You may do so without buying.)

Answer (score 2):

A 56 is around your size, but height, inseam, and the bike's nominal size are not enough to know whether you'll be able to clear the top tube. This is because the top tube slope (if any) and bottom bracket height also come in play here. Many manufacturers publish a "standover height" number that takes these into account, also given the size of the tires that come on the bike. These numbers can be useful, but on sloping top tube bikes they're always approximate at best. On your end, choice of shoes makes a difference too.